# function returning data but not showing

Tags: reactjs, api, object

I have this component

```
const SummaryBar = props => {
  const { MainObject} = props;

  const localGetUserFromID = userID => {
    getEmailFromId(userID).then(results => {
      return results.data.Title; //Comment: This one returning friendly name
    });
  };

     return (<span>Hello {localGetUserFromID(MainObject.AuthorId)}</span>)
}
```

but when I render it somehow the its only showing Hello and not the output I am getting from my localGetUserFromID function. Am I doing wrong? Note the AuthorId is being pass to an API and the MainObject came from the App Level,

FYI when I try to debug it using dev tools the function is retuning the text I am look for.

Comment: You have an async function, meaning the data isn't available as return value of your promise call, but only available when it has completed. You should rather go for a stateful component, get the data in componentwillmount, and update the local state, and render that state (provided, you don't have another statemanagement in your app available)

Comment: I have a question if I do that is the props already available inside the componentwillmount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localGetUserFromID()` returns nothing, that is, `undefined`, and that's why you see `Hello` only.

And because `localGetUserFromID()` makes an asynchronous call to get an email from user ID, it doesn't have to be in `render()` method. Now this component is defined as a state-less component, but you can re-define it as a stateful component, call the `getEmailFromId()` in `componentDidMount()` life-cycle method, and use a return value as an internal state.

Then you can show a value of the internal state after `Hello`.

```
class SummaryBar extends Component {
  // Skipping prop type definition.

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      username: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { MainObject: { AuthorId } } = this.props
    getEmailFromId(AuthorId).then((results) => {
      this.setState({
        username: results.data.title,
      })
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    const { username } = this.state
    return (
      <span>
        Hello { username }
      </span>
    ) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When things run when debugging but not when running and you are using promises as you are, the 99% of the times is because promises hasn't been resolved when you print.

`localGetUserFromID` indeed returns a promise that resolves to the friendly name.

You can just prepend `await` to `localGetUserFromID(MainObject.AuthorId)` and rewrite you return as this:

```
return (<span>Hello {await localGetUserFromID(MainObject.AuthorId)}</span>)
```